# Googl sheets function

Tags: google-sheets-formula, equation

I need help with an equation for work I need to be able to highlight start date and end date if todays date is in range, so how I want it to work is when the start date of a premotion and end date is in range of today's date, I want the whole start and end date to be highlight until the premotion range is over so start date is A2 and end date B2

I've tried videos but the only tutorial that ive found is when a certain date land on the range then it is highlighted but I need the whole start and end date to highlight when it's in range of today's date and so on till the premotion is over

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=($A2<=TODAY())*($B2>=TODAY())
```

[image]